# Comparing two listBuffer in Scala

Tags: scala, object-oriented-analysis, listbuffer

I have a class like :

```
case class (a: String, b: String, c: ListBuffer)
```

I have multiple object of this class.
I want output class in such way that if two object have similar **listbuffer** element in that, then it should add in result only once (duplicate should be avoided).

Comment: When `ListBuffer`s should be considered similar? What about other values - should they be ignored in comparison? Is this a rule in your code or an exception when it comes to comparing values of this type? Perhaps `case class` is not the right tool here?

Comment: @yogesh could you elaborate?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok first entry point is first variable to check, but thats not an issue as its simple string. so we can say that like first we need to check for first variable (a) if those are same then move on to the listBuffer

Comment: If you do something like `x.a == y.a && x.b == y.b && x.listBuffer == y. listBuffer` then this is how default `case class` implementation works. If you want to change it you write your own code.

Comment: @Yogesh a `case class` MUST NOT contain mutable variables.